# Concatenate cross tab values with dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe `df` of the following type:

```
ID   Result Other_val
1    A      y
2    B      x
2    A      x
3    C      abc
```

After using `pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Result)`, I get a crosstab like this:

```
Result  A  B  C
ID
1       1  0  0
2       1  1  0
3       0  0  1
```

I wish to now concatenate these values to the end of my original dataframe (after removing the already present `Result` column) to get something like this:

```
ID   A   B   C   Other_val
1    1   0   0   y
2    1   1   0   x
3    0   0   1   abc
```

However, I am stumped. I can't seem to use `pd.concat()` to form the above table because of the strange way the cross-tab table is indexed.

Any help?

Comment: `Other_val` could also be `x y abc`, or am I wrong? How do you decide about the order there?

Comment: @Cleb, you're right! that was a typo- fixed it

Comment: Hope the link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe/47152692#47152692

Comment: @Wen: Great link, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Cleb Yw~:-)!~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `pd.crosstab([df.ID, df.Other_val], df.Result)`, because you need to group ID and Other_val.

```
In [5]: pd.crosstab([df.ID, df.Other_val], df.Result)
Out[5]: 
Result        A  B  C
ID Other_val         
1  y          1  0  0
2  x          1  1  0
3  abc        0  0  1
```

Comment: That's far cleaner than mine and should probably the accepted answer (+ 1); did not even think about it but just blindly merged the dataframes... ;) You could still add a `.reset_index()`, if you like...

Comment: That's why I at least upvoted your answer and also recommended to accept yours (see comment below my answer).

Comment: I just came across this! Much cleaner and efficient- thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Result)
```

and then either

```
df_final = df.drop('Result', axis=1).drop_duplicates('ID').join(df2, on='ID')
```

which gives

```
   ID Other_val  A  B  C
0   1         y  1  0  0
1   2         x  1  1  0
3   3       abc  0  0  1
```

If you want to reorder the columns you obtain your desired outcome

```
df_final = df_final[['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Other_val']]

   ID  A  B  C Other_val
0   1  1  0  0         y
1   2  1  1  0         x
3   3  0  0  1       abc
```

You can also use `concat` like this

```
pd.concat([df.drop('Result', axis=1).drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID'), df2], axis=1)

   Other_val  A  B  C
ID                   
1          y  1  0  0
2          x  1  1  0
3        abc  0  0  1
```

Comment: @mDe: Glad it helped; you might want to look at laguittemh's answer though, which seems far cleaner (you can always unaccept my answer and accept his). I did not even think about this but just blindly merged the dataframes... :)